# Hats are not appearing correctly on expanded usercards in Safari

Tags: bug, user-interface, winter-bash, user-card, safari

If I hover over a user with an expandable usercard, the hat is only showing on the profile pic of the usercard for a very short time. After that, it teleports back to the original picture.

I don't want my hat to travel through cyberspace. **Please make it stop!**

I'm using Safari 11.0.2 on macOS 10.13.

[image: hats appear only for a very short time]